# Rails: want to display the content of subclass according to its ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subclass, matching

I have update my code as following:

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
 create_table :addresses do |t|
  t.integer :address_type_id
  t.text :street
  t.string :city
  t.string :state, :limit => 2
  t.integer :zip
  t.references :entry

  t.timestamps
 end
  add_index :addresses, :entry_id
...

class CreateAddressTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up 
  create_table :address_types do |t|
  t.string :name
end
```

My models:

```
class AddressType < ActiveRecord::Base 
 has_many :addresses 
 attr_accessible :name 
end

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name
end
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry
  belongs_to :address_type
  attr_accessible :city, :state, :street, :zip
end
```

And my _form file:

```
 ...
 .form-inputs
= f.collection_select (:address_type_id, AddressType.all, :id, :name)
= f.input :street
= f.input :city
```

After I hit "create", an error says "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: address_type_id". I know I must make some mistakes somewhere?

Comment: If you're going to update your question, edit your question instead of the answers. If you would like to notify anyone who answered, leave a comment below their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your Object relations, you could do something like this:

```
# in view (HAML)
%th Address Type
%td= address.address_type.name
```

Maybe (depending on how you want it to work) sometimes an Address will not have a AddressType linked with it. To support this and prevent for Nil exceptions, you could do the following:

```
# in view (HAML)
%th Address Type
%td= address.address_type.try(:name)
```

The `try` method is explicit in its name: it will try to call the method (here `name`) to the AddressType object. If this one is `nil` or doesn't respond to the `name` method, it will return `nil` and not raise a NoMethodError for Nil:NilClass.

**Your relations are not set correctly:**

An Address can only have one (max) Address Type. In the other way, an Address Type can set to zero, one or many Addresses. Which means, in Rails (and common language, easily readeable and understandable):

- An Address `belongs_to` an AddressType
- An AddressType `has_many` Addresses

These relations can be set like following: (I took off the unrelevant other statements)

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :address_type
end

class AddressType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses # note: Rails need plural relations for has_many
end
```

This means the Address  table will have a column named `address_type_id` which will refer to a specific AddressType (Home, Work or other). (you may have to run a migration in order to destroy the previous column in AddressType and add one in the Address table).

**Edit**:

I have updated my code as following:

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def self.up
     create_table :addresses do |t|
      t.integer :address_type_id
      t.text :street
      t.string :city
      t.string :state, :limit => 2
      t.integer :zip
      t.references :entry

      t.timestamps
    end
     add_index :addresses, :entry_id
 ...

 class CreateAddressTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up 
    create_table :address_types do |t|
    t.string :name
  end
```

My models:
    class AddressType < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :addresses
        attr_accessible :name
    end

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses
    attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name
end
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :entry
    belongs_to :address_type
    attr_accessible :city, :state, :street, :zip
end
```

And my _form file:

```
 ...
 .form-inputs
= f.collection_select (:address_type_id, AddressType.all, :id, :name)
= f.input :street
= f.input :city
```

After I hit "create", an error says "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: address_type_id". I know I must make some mistakes somewhere?

Comment: I tried your solutions and an error prompted out: "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: address_types.address_id: SELECT  "address_types".* FROM "address_types"  WHERE "address_types"."address_id" = 3 LIMIT 1". I am not sure where I did go wrong?

Comment: I didn't add_index address_id in my addressType migrate, is it the reason?

Comment: I think there is a confusion: The Address object should have the `address_type_id`, not the AddressType. Your relations are not set correctly, an address belongs_to an AddressType and an AddressType has_many Addresses (tell me if you need some code to help you)

Comment: Thanks, MrYoshiji. Would you please provide me some code, it would be of great help to understand these concepts and relationships.

Comment: Thank you MrYoshiji, I have updated my code in my question but it comes with new errors, please help me out.

Comment: I realized I missed adding address_type_id to attr_accessible, and it worked. Thank you very much MrYoshiji!